# Adding timestamp before each STDOUT line inside perlscript

Tags: perl, programming

In a perl script, I am capturing all the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` using the below code:

```
open STDOUT, '>>', "$log_file" or die "Can't redirect STDOUT: $!";
open STDERR, ">&STDOUT"  or die "Can't add to  STDOUT: $!";
main();
```

Here I am logging all those are generated from `main()` but how can I add a timestamp infront of each line of `STDOUT` ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the reason you want to do this is so that you don't have to include "print scalar localtime" for each print statement. If so, I'd recommend doing this in a simpler fashion.

Instead of using `print` on each print statement, make separate functions for logging error messages, informational messages and printing output. Like this:

```
sub logmsg {
  print (scalar localtime() . " @_\n");
}

sub logerr {
  print STDERR (scalar localtime() . "ERROR: @_\n");
}

sub debug {
  if ($debug) {
    print "DEBUG: @_\n";
  }
}
```

Then, within the script I will always use `logmsg` or `logerr` as appropriate. This makes it easy to change where the log messages go by altering those few functions. In your case, you could also change the log functions to write directly to the file instead of to STDOUT/STDERR. (In my own case, I will often use syslog instead, so I will remove the timestamp code and instead use e.g. `Sys::Syslog` with appropriate facility and log level.)

Comment: Yes I have actually more than hundreds of prints from the `main()` in to the log file. So I dont want to use print date infront of each.